# git: How to ignore last commit?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

On my `main` branch I have several working versions of my code. Last commit (ref as `V3`) has a major bug. To fix it I reverted to `V2` and updated relevant feature properly. I wish to know to how push my commit to `V3` will be totally ignored.

[image]

```
* 8741be8 (HEAD -> main) fixing crashes - not final
| * 086c504 (origin/main, origin/HEAD) after revert
|/  
* 9d1e3d7 update to bootlog
* 8dfe4a7 fix MQTT resets
* 4f714a1 b4 update windows
* 65ab05a  update to avoid disconnects and resets
* 5e4b5eb from linux
* f5f1126 after protangoues resets
* f5f3bb7 first commit
```

Comment: It is unclear if you reverted (in Git terms) or if you actually have the graph as in your image. Reverting in Git would create a commit on its own. Furthermore, you show two `V3*` commits which seems a bit odd. Please add the output of `git log --oneline --graph --all`

Comment: you are right regarding `V3*`  it should be only one instance. I went `HEAD~1` . adding graph

Comment: you could also do `git commit --amend`

Comment: To push the new version to the remote and remove `086c504` from the master branch, you can use `git push --force origin master` (depending on the settings on the remote, you may need to allow forced pushes first).

Comment: @ASR while true, this will not solve the problem of the remote having a different history than the local branch.

Comment: @SimonDoppler, yes `--amend` alone won't help but pushing to remote with `--force` will help replace the history on the remote as well.

Comment: That is what they want, they want to remove the bad commit from the remote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you stated, you reverted `V3`, so `V3` does not exist anymore on your local `main` branch.

Is it right? If yes, you have to rewrite the history on server (be carefully), by the following commands:

```sh
git checkout main # Optional, if you are on another branch
git push --force origin main
```

Comment: when tried to `git checkout main` got this : `Already on 'main'
Your branch and 'origin/main' have diverged,
and have 1 and 1 different commits each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)`

Comment: My `git checkout` step is optional, obvsiously. The message you received is due the fact that on remote there is the `V3` which you want to remove by the forced push, but I suggest you to better inspect you local and remote history.